# Asset validation issue when uploading app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am tryng to uploading an app to the app store via xcode (13.4.1) and i keep getting

"App Store Connect Operation Error"

and below that, it just says

"Asset validation failed"

Nothing else. I have no idea how to resolve this as it doesn't specify exactly which asset. Anyone else run into the same issue?

Comment: Usr `Transporter` to send the ipa and it will tell you about the error exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Download this app, and install it.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

When you finish archiving then now distribute it. Choose AppStore > Export (Not upload) -> You have your *.ipa > Drag it to Transfer app.

Transfer app require you to login with your DEVELOPER Apple ID.

This app gives you detailed results about uploading to TestFlight and its upload speed is very fast.